# Cli mirage routes not working in acceptace test

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit, ember-cli-mirage

I was trying acceptance test for login page, using cli mirage as mock server. Routes defined in a mirage works fine, when accessing it from application. But when trying it in ember test it returns

Mirage: Your Ember app tried to POST 'http://localhost:4200/tests?module=Acceptance | login', but there was no route defined to handle this request. Define a route that matches this path in your mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?

**Acceptance Test**

```
test('visiting /login', function(assert) {
  server.create('login', { username: 'xxx@test.com', password: 'password' });
  visit('/login');

  fillIn('input[placeholder="Email"]', 'xxx@test.com');
  fillIn('input[placeholder="Password"]', 'password');
  click('button.btn-primary');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/route');
  });
});
```

**Mirage/config**

```
import Mirage from 'ember-cli-mirage';
export default function() {
this.post('/token', function(db, request) {
  var params = formEncodedToJson(request.requestBody);

  if(params.username === "xxx@test.com && params.password === "password") {
    return {
      "auth":"Pass$Word",
      "token_type":"bearer"
    };
  } else{
    var body = { errors: 'Email or password is invalid' };
    return new Mirage.Response(401, {}, body);
  }
});
```

How to rectify this issue? someone help me please.

Comment: can you add the code that calls the `/token` api?

Comment: var credentials = this.getProperties('username', 'password'),
                    authenticator = 'authenticator:custom';

                this.get('session').authenticate(authenticator, credentials).then( () => {
                  // Redirect to landing page
                });

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in environment configuration. After defined configurations for test worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I forgot to define endpoints such as `ENV.APP.registrationEndpoint` in the "test" part of my` environment.js`

Answer (score 0):

for me, I have explicitly add host etc because without it, it resolves to a different port from my mirage config.js